# Efficent Way To Show SMS Inbox In ListView

Tags: android, sms, adapter

i want to show all user inbox SMS in ListView.I use a method to get all SMS first (and keep it on my SMS model), and then use my custom BaseAdapter to show that.
But it's very slow and sometimes in weak device caused "not responding".
i guess because it get all SMS once and it's not lazy. Have any idea to improve performance of this ?

my helper method:

```
public List<SMS> getAllSMS() {
  List<SMS> unreadSms = new ArrayList<SMS>();
  Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "", null, null);
  while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    SMS item = new SMS();
    item.setId(cur.getInt(0));
    item.setThreadId(cur.getInt(1));
    item.setNumber(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
    item.setName(getContactName(item.getNumber()));
    item.setDate(new Date(cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"))));
    item.setMessage(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
    unreadSms.add(item);
  }
  cur.close();

  return unreadSms;
}
```

my adapter:

```
public class SMSAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<SMS> items;
final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());

  public SMSAdapter(Context context, List<SMS> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
  }

  @Override public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
  }

  @Override public SMS getItem(int i) {
    return items.get(i);
  }

  @Override public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (view == null) {
      view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_sms_list, viewGroup, false);
      viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
      view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
      viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    final SMS item = getItem(i);

    Uri contactUri = null;
    try {
      contactUri = PhoneUtil.getPhotoUri(context, item.getNumber());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Picasso.with(context)
        .load(contactUri)
        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_avatar)
        .into(viewHolder.imgAvatar);

    if (item.getName() != null && !item.getName().isEmpty()) {
      viewHolder.txtName.setText(item.getName());
    } else {
      viewHolder.txtName.setText(item.getNumber());
    }
    final PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
    persianCalendar.setTimeInMillis(item.getDate().getTime());
    viewHolder.txtDate.setText(
        simpleDateFormat.format(item.getDate()) + " " + persianCalendar.getPersianShortDate());
    viewHolder.txtMessage.setText(item.getMessage());

    viewHolder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        //items.remove(item);
        PhoneUtil.removeSMS(context, item.getId(), item.getThreadId());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    });

    return view;
  }

  private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imgAvatar, imgDelete;
    public TextView txtName;
    public TextView txtDate;
    public TextView txtMessage;

    public ViewHolder(View viewItem) {
      final TypefaceProvider typefaceProvider = new TypefaceProvider(viewItem.getContext());
      imgAvatar = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
      imgDelete = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.img_delete);
      txtName = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
      txtDate = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
      txtMessage = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_message);

      typefaceProvider.setTypeface(txtName);
      typefaceProvider.setTypeface(txtDate);
      typefaceProvider.setTypeface(txtMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my adapter and use CursorAdapter instead of BaseAdapter and don't get all SMS before load my adapter. performance improved and lag reduced.

hope this help somebody.